# Javacard using a final variable or just using a value

Tags: javacard

For example:

i) using a value

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer,(short)(offset+20), keyTrack, PARAMETER_OFFSET, **(short) 6**);
```

ii) using a final variable

```
final static short length=6;
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer,(short)(offset+20), keyTrack, PARAMETER_OFFSET, **length**);
```

so which one is better for javacard development? (let's just say I'm gonna use a lot of "6" later on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `final static` is better if related to constants. The size of the generated binary for both cases are the same. However, ii) has advantage in **code readability** and also **easier to maintain** (if you need to change the value, you only need to change in one place).

NOTE: to avoid confusion, a variable is written as camelCase while a constant (final static) is written using UPPER_CASE. Example:

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, (short) (offset + 20), 
                        keyTrack, PARAMETER_OFFSET, LEN_OF_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields that are final and static and of a primitive type are inlined by the Java compiler as discussed in the [Java Language Specification, section 13.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9). This is independent of JavaCard because it happens even before the conversion to JavaCard binary format (CAP file) takes place.

So, the final binary code will be strictly identical.